# Browser identification of dropdown list

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown list but it only works in Firefox, it does not work in Google Chrome. Can kindly tell me what I'm missing?

```
<p>
<label for="Department">Your Department: </label>
<datalist id="Department">
<option value="Microbiology">
<option value="Mathematics">
<option value="Animal sciences">
<option value="Agricultural Economics">
<option value="Medicine">
<option value="Pharmacy">
<option value="Human Nutrition">
<option value="English">
<option value="Dentistry">
</datalist>
<input type="text" name="Department" id="Department" �
list="Department" />
<p>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/datalist

Comment: @Confused The `datalist` element is perfectly valid. And this seems to work just fine ([demo](http://codepen.io/boaz/pen/rkGbx)) in Chrome, unless you're using a very outdated version of it.

Comment: If I use only 7 elements (option values) it works hm... Try to use select instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Chrome only supports datalist tag if version >= 20.0

Further it's not supported by Safari, so better use select.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't miss anything. It is supported in the following browsers versions:

Google Chrome: **20.0+**
Internet Explorer: **10.0+**
Firefox: **4.0+**
Safari: **Not supported**
Opera: **9.0+**

For more details visit http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's an HTML5 tag. So, your browser have to support it, otherwise it will not do what you want.

Pay also attention to the browser version.

See http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist for more details.